# Getting error when runnig plotly.express on runnig code in ipynb

Tags: python

I wrote the code in ipynb as same as the video class :

```
import plotly.express as px 

grafico = px.histogram(tabela, x="duracao_contrato", color="cancelou",color_discrete_map="blues")

grafico.show()
```

but when I run the code the message that shows is NameError: name 'tabela' is not defined

What I'm doing wrong? Could someone help me please?

I followed all the teacher's suggestions and installed everything he asked. I'm using VSCode on Linux Ubuntu, does it have any specific extensions that I should check if I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Well, the error is self-explanatory.  You haven't defined anywhere in your code what ```tabela``` is.  You're either missing an import, or you're missing a definition.

Comment: Where is it defined in your code?   You've only used it in your second line.  There's no mention elsewhere in your code.

Comment: But it's defined in the code. I ran other parts that was with this and it was ok. How I could fix it?

Comment: Then colour me confused.  Please clarify where it is defined.

Comment: I realize now What I was missing. I had to run each part again in sequence. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So what I'm understanding is that the script you posted depends on a script that is run before this?  As in that script defines ```tabela```?

Comment: Smells like a workbook where OP is showing us just one cell but a previous cell defines `tabela`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gleyce, I believe you watched Lira Hashtag. I'm also following the classes and I ran into  the same situation. I basically ran all the codes again since of the beginning or you can just apply the "Run All".
If that doesn't work, try to retire the "discrete_color" part.